# Floating Action button item can't show toast

Tags: java, android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I have a problem dealing with `FloatingActionButton` with sub `menu`. i need to add actions when the sub menu is clicked. I've just got this `FloatingActionButton` code from the net, i want to put actions in it, thanks for the help.

this is my `FloatingActionButton`:

[image]

im using  `com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2` library

this is my onCreateView code:

```
FloatingActionButton fabsnail = v.findViewById(R.id.fabsnailtrail);
FloatingActionButton fabprox = v.findViewById(R.id.fabproximity);
FloatingActionButton fabnav = v.findViewById(R.id.fabnavigations);

fabsnail.setOnClickListener(this);
fabprox.setOnClickListener(this);
fabnav.setOnClickListener(this);

fabsnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Snail Trail!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

  fabprox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Proximity!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

fabnav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Navigations!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
     });
```

And this is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="#a21e23"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="#a21e23"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
    fab:menu_labels_style="@style/MenuLabelsStyle"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_icon="@mipmap/negative"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
    fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
    fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
    fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
    fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_position="right"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabsnailtrail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/snailtrail"
        fab:fab_label=" Snail Trail "
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#a21e23"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabproximity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/proximity"
        fab:fab_label=" Proximity "
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#a21e23"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabnavigations"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/navigations"
        fab:fab_label=" Navigations "
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#a21e23"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add **show** method in `Toast` .

Try to use this .

```
 Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Navigations!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Good luck to you.@MNGorospe